# Chromium Scrapbook in which path are stored the pages?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I need to save **a lot** of html pages, which I couldn't get using script (like urllib in python) because they are full of javascript and they require a full browser to be elaborated. Analyzing the source code it's impossible at the moment for (as I don't know anything about it exept some html).

How browsers save the pages is fine, but I would repeat the action many times. I found Chromium Scrapbook, an extension for Chrome, which allows to save the pages open in all the tabs with just one click.

Do you know in which path are they saved? When I open them via the extension in the address bar I don't see the path, but the full html code itself.

If you don't, do you know any other extesion (preferably for Chrome, but also for Firefox would be good) that does a similar job?

I already tried HTTrack and it has failed.